# why cant my streamlit cloud upload read my png image

Tags: python, localhost, cloud, streamlit

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBkOP.png)

```
from pathlib import Path
import streamlit as st
from PIL import Image
from streamlit_option_menu import option_menu
from Page_Details import home, about, contact

current_directory = Path.cwd()
images_folder = current_directory / 'Images'

try:
    headliner_path = images_folder / 'Headliner.png'
    main_image = Image.open(headliner_path)
    st.image (main_image, caption="Naloxone Awareness", use_column_width=True) 
except FileNotFoundError:
    st.error(f"Image 'Headliner.png' not found in '{images_folder}'. Please check the file path.") 
except Exception as e:
    st.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcyFV.png) (Console output in screen0shot)

```
FileNotFoundError: This app has encountered an error. The original error message is 
redacted to prevent data leaks. Full error details have been recorded in the logs (if you're on 
Streamlit Cloud, click on 'Manage app' in the lower right of your app).
```

Traceback:

```
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/streamlit/runtim
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/mount/src/naloxone/Volunteer_Website/main.py", line 6, in <modul
    main_image = Image.open('Images/Headliner.png')
File "/home/adminuser/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", l 
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
```

Works fine when I load it on local host and on Anaconda prompt. However when I click deploy and create the app on streamlit cloud it fails cuz it says that it cant read the 'headliners.png' file even though it's in the images folder next to it which my code specifies.

I tried chatgpt and searching on youtube for a solution without luck.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I had no issue running it on streamlit cloud. However, understand that streamlit cloud will execute your app from your base repository, so it will look for "Headliner.png" from somewhere like this `<repo path>/Images/Headliner.png`. In other words, streamlit cloud's CWD is `/mount/src/<repo name>`, so it will execute your main app from that directory.

This is good:

- `<repo path>/Images/Headerliner.png`
- `<repo path>/myapp/main.py`

This won't work unless you adjust your code's `current_directory` or `images_folder` variable

- `<repo path>/myapp (or any dir)/Images/Headliner.png`
- `<repo path>/myapp/main.py`

Just a side note, the main.py is the `main file path` it can be anywhere inside the repository.

Comment: how do I adjust my codes current directory?

Comment: Image 'Headliner.png' not found in '/mount/src/naloxone/Images'. Please check the file path. is what I get now, but i have headliner.png in my images folder

Comment: Sorry for the late response, you can try this `images_folder = current_directory / 'naloxone' / 'Images'`

Comment: I'm taking a second look. Ignore my comment above, you may have it right. You should pass an absolute path here `Image.open('Images/Headliner.png')`. Use your `headliner_path` variable. , You can remove your own Exception and see if it's throwing a different Exception, and could you include your directory tree?

Comment: Or try this: `Image.open('/mount/src/naloxone/Images/Headliner.png')` that's full path that streamlit is using and what you're trying to do based of your original code. Make sure the directory and file are spelled correctly.

Comment: Also check if the permission is correct in git `git ls-files -s Images/Headliner.png` it should have <###>644 the last three digit is the permission.